# Библиотека на Python, которая позволит выбирать элементы из списка в cmd динамично

Tags: python, cmd, библиотеки

У меня есть массив ссылок и пользователю нужно выбрать эту ссылку. Но я не хочу, чтобы пользователь вводил id этой ссылки в cmd, а визуально нажал в cmd на эту сслыку или зажал стрелочку вверх, дошёл до нужной ссылки и выбралась эта ссылка. И вот нужна такая библиотека, которая делает выбор пользователя более динамичным и удобным

Comment: Я просто видел такую технологию, но не запомнил библиотеку, а с tkinter много лишнего, хочется сделать простую программу без лишнего

Comment: вам нужен стандартный модуль https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html либо его порт на windows https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/

Answer (score -1):

```
import keyboard
import os
from termcolor import cprint
id = 0

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    foo  = ['Яблоко', 'банан', 'помидор', 'огурец']
    global id
    
    if e.event_type == 'down' and (e.name in ['down', 'up', 'enter'] or e.name.isdigit() ):
        os.system('cls')
        
        if e.name == 'up' or e.name == 'down':
            id = ( id + (1, -1)[e.name == 'up'] ) % len(foo)
            [ cprint(el, 'white','on_yellow') if id == i else print(el) for i, el in enumerate(foo) ]
            
        else:
            id = id if e.name == 'enter' else int(e.name) % len(foo)
            print( foo[id])
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Не совсем то, но сойдёт